# Use of MemoryCache in .net core mvc 2.1 and application will be deployed on azure WebApp

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-redis-cache

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I am creating a .net core MVC 2.1 application. I am thinking of caching master data , using details mentioned in above link.
My application would be deployed on Win WebApp on azure. WebApp scales itself based on load.
No idea how caching will behave in this case. Any any moment if multiple webservers are running, each would maintain its own cache? 
If this fails, is Managed Redis is the only choice on azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core has built-in support for distributed caching and one of the default implementations of a distributed cache in ASP.NET Core also uses Redis and SQL server. You could read more **[here](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/a-guide-to-caching-in-asp.net-core)**